# Deleting elements onClick in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Row Component that i am importing into my App.js component and apparently i  but the delete function doesn't seem to be deleting the correct row. Even if i delete the second one, it deletes the last one first. So basically if i click delete on second row, it should delete the second one not the third etc.

My App.js or my root component looks like this: -

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Row from './Row.js'

class App extends Component {
   state = {
      rows: [
       {value: 'row1', options:[1,2,3,4,5] },
       {value: 'row2', options:[1,2,3,4,5] },
       {value: 'row3', options:[ 1,2,3,4,5 ]}
     ]
  }

  updateValue = (e, idx) => {
  const rows = [...this.state.rows];
  rows[idx].value = e.target.value;
 this.setState({
  rows,
 });
}

addRow = () => {
const rows = [...this.state.rows, {value:'', options: [1,2,3,4,5}];
 this.setState({
    rows,
   });
 }

 deleteRow = (idx) => {
 const copy = [...this.state.rows]
 copy.splice(idx,1)
 this.setState ({
 rows:copy
  })
}

render() {
   return (
      <div>
    {
  this.state.rows.map ( (row,idx) => {
    return (
      <Row 
      key = {idx} 
      value = { row.value } 
      onChange = { (e) => this.updateValue(e,idx) } 
      delete = { this.deleteRow.bind(this,idx) } />
       )
    })
   }
 <button onClick = {this.addRow}> Add </button>
 </div>
     )
   }
} 

 export default App;
```

And my row component looks like this:-

```
const Row = ( props) => {
let options = props.options.map(opt => <option key={opt}>{opt}</option>);

return (
   <div>
    <input value= { props.value } onChange={ props.onChange }></input>
    <select>
        {options}
    </select>
    <button onClick = { props.delete} > Delete </button>  
   </div>
  )
}

export default Row
```

I asked a similar question yesterday [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59924070/delete-items-onclick-using-reactjs/59924080?noredirect=1#comment105971675_59924080) but didn't realize at the time that the items weren't being deleted from the right position?

Comment: Dont u think u r missing `this` i.e. `this.props` ?

Comment: Your example actually seems to be working properly for me. I commented out the options rendering in your `Row` component, but that's a different issue than deleting the rows.

Comment: It works for me too. Fixed several syntactic errors and it ran correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
deleteRow = (item) => {
 let filtered = this.state.rows.filter(row=>row.value!==item.value);
 this.setState ({
 rows: filtered
  })
}
```

pass row to your delete function

```
    <Row 
      key = {idx} 
      value = { row.value } 
      onChange = { (e) => this.updateValue(e,idx) } 
      delete = {()=>this.deleteRow(row) } />
       )
```

if every row(object) is having unique id then use that id instead of value
like-

```
 let filtered = this.state.rows.filter(row=>row.id!==item.id);
```

Comment: @Somethingwhatever check now by changing both mentioned code

Comment: if multiple rows shared the same value, this would delete extra rows

Comment: @khuynh what would you suggest then? because my code doesn't seem to be doing what is expected :|

Comment: This is bad practise. new state should not old state like that. Then you should use function for setting state

Comment: can you verify your code in the OP @Somethingwhatever? I ran the code you provided and it seems to be working as intended (it deletes the correct row)

Comment: @pethel This is perfectly fine and it's actually a better practice compared to `splice`ing the current state.

Comment: @khuynh I am certain that it is not deleting the correct row.

Comment: I agree this is better practice than splicing the states (given the rows have a unique id to properly filter on). However, I believe it is slightly better practice to use the `prevProps` argument with `setState`. This guarantees that the state will be up to date.

Comment: @technophyle https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3

You missed the point. I mean you should use the setState that takes a function. Filtering is preferable over splice, yes.